# Google Multiplayer RealTime invitations

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games, multiplayer

I'm trying to check for invitations on the start of the app, but every time the code runs. The bundle returns null. I saw on google's developer website that

> The Task returned will not be null, but the Bundle returned from the Task may be null if it was already received or there is no related data found.

This is the code I am using to check for invitations:

```
private void checkForInvitation() {
    Games.getGamesClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).getActivationHint()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Bundle>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Bundle bundle) {
                    System.out.println(bundle);
                    if(bundle != null) {
                        System.out.println("three line");
                        Invitation invitation = bundle.getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_INVITATION);
                        if (invitation != null) {
                            System.out.println("fourth line");
                            notificationText = String.valueOf(bundle.size());
                            RoomConfig.Builder builder = RoomConfig.builder(mRoomUpdateCallback)
                                    .setInvitationIdToAccept(invitation.getInvitationId());
                            mJoinedRoomConfig = builder.build();
                            // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
                            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: Have you tried switching on the enable multiplayer button in the Google Console for developers?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps you, but I used the same code from the GoogleDeveloper site to check for invitations and my app crashes every time it starts **without** an invitation.

I get: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.

When I get an invitation notification and start the app via statusbar, it don't crashs and works like expected. So this is ok but i'm not able to start the app without a crash as long there is no invitation.

My solution not to crash without an invitation, is:

```
new OnSuccessListener<Bundle>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Bundle bundle) {
        if (bundle != null){
            Invitation invitation = bundle.getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_INVITATION);
            if (invitation != null) {
                //do what you want to do when invitation reveived
            } 
        }
    }
}
```